# I have a list view, how can I add a search for items?

Tags: search

class Sleep : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var listofsleep= ArrayList<ModleSleep>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sleep)

  var  adaptersleep = SleepAdapter(this,listofsleep)
    lvsleep.adapter = adaptersleep


    listofsleep.add(ModleSleep(getString(R.string.SleepAnalysis), getString(R.string.SleepAnalysisDes)))
    listofsleep.add(ModleSleep(getString(R.string.SleepAnalysis), getString(R.string.SleepAnalysisDes)))
    listofsleep.add(ModleSleep(getString(R.string.SleepAnalysis), getString(R.string.SleepAnalysisDes)))
    listofsleep.add(ModleSleep(getString(R.string.SleepAnalysis), getString(R.string.SleepAnalysisDes)))
    listofsleep.add(ModleSleep(getString(R.string.SleepAnalysis), getString(R.string.SleepAnalysisDes)))

}
```

}

class SleepAdapter:ArrayAdapter {
constructor(context: Sleep, sleep: ArrayList) : super(context, 0, sleep)

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var listviewsleep: View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_sleep, parent, false)
    var name3: String? = null
    var des3: String? = null;
    var ModleSleep = getItem(position)
    name3 = ModleSleep?.name3
    des3 = ModleSleep?.des3
    listviewsleep.tvsleep.text = name3
    listviewsleep.Sdescription.text = des3
    listviewsleep.onclicksleep.setOnClickListener {
        val intent= Intent(context, onclicksleep::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("dessleep",des3)
        context!!.startActivity(intent)
    }
    return listviewsleep

}
```

}

class ModleSleep(var name3: String,var des3:String)

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.